# url rewrite with wildcard possible with magento 2.x default set-up?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, redirect

I want to use wildcards for url redirects in Magento 2.x with basic Magento set-up. Whenever I add it, either via Import upload or manually added they do not work. Does anyone know if adding wildcards can work this way or do I need a module or extension to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whildcards don't work in url rewrites by default.
Url rewrites are just 1 on 1 mappings from one url to another (with or without redirect).
If you need to match multiple urls based on rules and do something with them, I recommend creating a custom router.
You can find some documentation in here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/routing.html
(it says v2.1 but it works for any 2.*).  Check the "Custom routers" section.